# Example of using assertj satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder with dynamic expected values

Tags: java, assertj

I didn't find any example of using `satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder` assertion of assertj, so here's a simple example:
I wanted to check that the actual list contains strings that end with the strings of the expected list, in any order.
Example of a valid test: `expected = {"abc","def","ghi"}, actual = {"1=def","ghi","234=abc"}`

```
package test;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test1 {

    private static void testSuffixes(List<String> expected, List<String> actual) {
        // Turn the expected strings into consumers
        Consumer<String>[] suffixTests = expected
                .stream()
                .map(expected -> {
                    Consumer<String> suffixTest = 
                       value -> Assertions.assertThat(value).endsWith(expected);
                    return suffixTest;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(new Consumer[0]);

        Assertions.assertThat(actual).satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder(suffixTests);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> expected = List.of("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
        List<String> actual = List.of("0=ABC", "3=GHI", "DEF");
        testSuffixes(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

When the actual values end with the expected strings, the execution ends with code 0.
When the actual values don't end with the expected strings, the execution ends with AssertionError:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError:  Expecting
> actual:   ["0=ABC", "DEF1", "3=GHI"] to satisfy all the consumers in
> any order.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? The observed behavior is as expected. Examples of `satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder` are available in its Javadoc: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder(java.util.function.Consumer...)

Comment: @StefanoCordio - the problem I faced was that my expected values weren't constant. The example you linked uses hard-coded values for the tests.
I needed to create consumers for the assertions, based on a list of strings.
(I added "with dynamic expected values" to the title to clarify)